# Mongodb How to delete/clear an array in an other array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections

I would like to now how you can delete/clear an entire array that is inside another array.

This is how my data looks like. I would like to know how i can clear out the array "companyvote". Any suggestions?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55529cbb056565e80d963fac"),
"email" : "test@test.be",
"img" : "\img\1920x12001431477435530.jpg",
"companyvote" : [ 
    "Lovely inc", 
    "Behond imagination"
],
"__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use **$unset** to remove the property like this

```
db.companies.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("55529cbb056565e80d963fac")},
    {$unset:{'companyvote':1}});
```

Or if you just want to clear the content of the array you can use **$set**

```
db.companies.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("55529cbb056565e80d963fac")}, {$set:{'companyvote':[]}})
```

To delete contents for all record, you just need to remove the filter by Id

```
db.companies.update({}, {$set:{'companyvote':[]}})
```

Comment: Thanks! But this deletes only one of the nested arrays. I want to be able to delete all of them.

Comment: Hello Sara, to delete all arrays you remove the filter condition out, please see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried to, but even with your updated code only the first record was deleted. I found a way to delete all the nested array, not sure if it is the right way, but it definetly works! You can check it out below.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the content of array for one record with

```
db.companies.update({ _id : ObjectId("55529cbb056565e80d963fac")}, {$set:{'companyvote':[]}});
or
db.companies.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("55529cbb056565e80d963fac")}, {$unset:{'companyvote':1}});
```

If you want to clear multi record, don't forget to add option

```
db.companies.update({}, {$set:{'companyvote':[]}}, {multi: true});
or
db.companies.update({}, {$unset:{'companyvote':1}}, {multi: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what really worked for me.

```
socket.on('deleteAllVotes', function() {
  Slides.find().exec(function(err, b) {
  for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      var allslides = b[i].companyvote;
      Slides.update({companyvote:allslides}, {$set:{'companyvote':[]}},function(err, b) {});
    }
  });
   socket.emit('deleteAllVotes');
});
```